# redirect user to another page when at login? Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Having some issues in solving this issue but. someone might knows this.
I would like to a user login into a regular joomla page but after they login with their account i would like them to be redirected to another page that is not inside joomla like articles etc. just a portal PHP page that i made using joomla functions. How would i make this possible thanks

I am not using any plug ins at the moment.
your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few login modules that allow you to select where to redirect the user to on successful login. I've used Signal, Core Design, and Yoo login modules.

Signal Login - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication/4181
Core Design - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication/2848
YOOlogin - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication/4421

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the standard mod_login module. You can point the user to any menu item so can theorectically point them to a 3rd part link or anywhere